# Django URL-Patterns: How to check if all url-names are distinct?

Tags: django, testing

I want to check if all names of the url patterns in my django project are distinct.

I don't want accidentally use one name twice.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback (down and close votes). Please speak to me. I am human being and would like to know what I am doing wrong :-)

Comment: You can use namespace in your urls. then your url names are like this: "yourapp:yourUrlName". look at [refference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces) for more example.

Comment: @mrash I know that namespaces exist. If a url has a different namespace, then it is no duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install `django-extensions` and run this command:

```
python manage.py show_urls
```

it will show you all urls in your app

To count names occurrences:

```
python manage.py show_urls -f verbose|grep 'URL Name' | sort | uniq -c
```

https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions

Comment: ok, this shows all urls. But how does it answer the question? Please elaborate.

Comment: Yes, this works. I do a last sorting by the number of duplicates like this: `python manage.py show_urls -f verbose|grep 'URL Name' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. :-( I amusing `Django==2.2.18` and `django-extensions==3.1.1` and get the error message `Unknown command: 'show_urls'`,

Comment: @physicalattraction You can downgrad to this version `django-extensions==2.2.5` it's working with Django 2.2, after running this command switch back to your current version of django-extensions if you need that specific version

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version which supports namespaces:

```
def test_url_name_not_duplicate(self):
    resolver = urlresolvers.get_resolver(None)
    names=defaultdict(list)
    for pattern, namespace in resolveutils.walk_url_patterns_with_namespace(resolver.url_patterns):
        if not pattern.name:
            continue
        name=pattern.name
        if namespace:
            name='%s:%s' % (namespace, name)
        if pattern.regex.groupindex:
            name='%s %s' % (name, sorted(pattern.regex.groupindex.keys()))
        names[name].append(pattern)
    duplicates=dict([(name, patterns) for name, patterns in names.items() if len(patterns)>1 and name not in ['login', 'logout']])
    self.assertFalse(duplicates, 'url patterns with duplicate names exist:\n%s' % '\n'.join(['url_name "%s":\n%s\n' % (
        name, '\n'.join(['    %s %s %s' % (pattern.regex.pattern, pattern.callback, inspect.getsourcefile(pattern.callback)) for pattern in patterns]))
                                                                                             for name, patterns in sorted(duplicates.items())]))
```

And the helper method:

```
def walk_url_patterns_with_namespace(patterns, namespace=''):
    for pattern in patterns:
      if hasattr(pattern, 'url_patterns'): # RegexURLResolver
          if namespace:
              namespace='%s:%s' % (namespace, pattern.namespace)
          for pattern, namespace in walk_url_patterns_with_namespace(pattern.url_patterns, namespace):
              yield pattern, namespace
      else: # RegexURLPattern
          yield pattern, namespace
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def test_url_name_not_duplicate(self):
    resolver = urlresolvers.get_resolver(None)
    names=defaultdict(list)
    for pattern in resolveutils.walk_url_patterns(resolver.url_patterns):
        if not pattern.name:
            continue
        names[pattern.name].append(pattern)
    duplicates=dict([(name, patterns) for name, patterns in names.items() if len(patterns)>1])
    self.assertFalse(duplicates, 'url patterns with duplicate names exist:\n%s' % '\n'.join(['url_name "%s":\n%s\n' % (
        name, '\n'.join(['    %s %s %s' % (pattern.regex.pattern, pattern.callback, inspect.getsourcefile(pattern.callback)) for pattern in patterns])) for name, patterns in sorted(duplicates.items())]))
```

Helper method walk_url_patterns()

```
def walk_url_patterns(patterns):
    for pattern in patterns:
      if hasattr(pattern, 'url_patterns'):
          for pattern in  walk_url_patterns(pattern.url_patterns):
              yield pattern
      else:
          yield pattern
```

Output if duplicates exists:

```
url_name "myquery":
    ^myquery/$ <function myquery> /home/user/src/foo/foo/views/query.py
    ^query/$ <function myquery> /home/user/src/foo/foo/views/query.py

url_name "bla":
    ^bla/$ <function bla> /home/user/src/foo/foo/views/bla.py
    ^bla2/$ <function bla2> /home/user/src/foo/foo/views/bla2.py
```

Comment: Does this handle namespaces? Will `myapp:index` and `myotherapp:index` be flagged as duplicates?

Comment: @Alasdair yes you are right. It does not handle namespaces. But it would be nice if it could. Unfortunately `RegexURLPattern` does not contain the namespace or its parent .... Any idea how to solve the question with namespace support?

Comment: I think that if the pattern has a `url_pattern` attribute, it should also have a `namespace` attribute. You could try adding `namespace` as an argument to your `walk_url_patterns` method, then returning the namespace when you yield. You might need a list `namespaces` in case they are nested.

Comment: @Alasdair since this answer has already a lot of comments, I wrote a second answer which supports namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the urls.py in directory /project_name/project_name/ act like that:

> url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")).

Then all your applications will using a different url. In your applications: make sure that your urls is like that:

> url(r'^download/$',   views.download, name='download'),
>   url(r'^anotherurl/$',   views.download, name='download'),

So all the urls will be different. In fact, I don't like the way putting the parameters into the url, like

> /polls/question/3/result/

It will make it easier to use a url name twice. I'd change it like that

> /possl/question/result/?question_id=3

Comment: thank you for explaining this. My intention is to have a reliable test which checks that no invalid configuration was done.

Comment: Your last comment about URL design is misguided, IMO. It [directly contradicts the Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/) (which the OP's example comes from), and proposes what most would call an ugly URL.

Comment: Yes, the django tutorial project is using the format such as : ` url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),` . But I still prefer take the question_id is as a parameter. And it will make it easier and tidier to post ajax requests when you are writing javascript.

Comment: @ramwin, *de gustibus non est disputandum*. It strikes me as much easier to write `{% url 'detail_view' question.id %}` in a template and also to use class-based detail views using the other format.

Answer (score 0):

Such a test should probably be **unnecessary if you structure your project well** into small individual django-apps, so that the routes of every app can be overseen easily.

Check out [this great slides](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/mar/15/slides/) from DjangoCon 2008 by James Bennett on some thoughts on when to introduce new apps and how to structure projects.

Comment: All testing is unnecessary if you do no faults :-) Please provide more details reasons why checking this automatically is a bad idea.

Comment: Nice objection. However I don't know how such faults like duplicated namespaces or names could ever happen, when structuring your apps properly.

Comment: Edit: To go more into your question, why it's a "bad idea": I more propose it's an unnecessary task. Because it's checking for problems that shouldn't exist, since there went some thoughts and planning in building apps and their routes. After this planning the "critical point" is "writing it down to the urls-file" which shouldn't fail either.

However - you probably found testing-methods here, so go for it. But maybe also think about whether your design could be improved to avoid those possible faults.